# How to get the true Euclidean remainder?

Tags: math, integer, standards, modulus, c89

I have two `unsigned long`s `a` and `q` and I would like to find a number n between 0 and q-1 such that n + a is divisible by q (without overflow).

In other words, I'm trying to find a (portable) way of computing `(-a)%q` which lies between 0 and q-1. (The sign of that expression is implementation-defined in C89.) What's a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is mathematically equivalent to (q - a) mod q, which in turn is equivalent to (q - (a mod q)) mod q. I think you should therefore be able to compute this as follows:

```
 unsigned long result = (q - (a % q)) % q;
```